# Question closed because considered opinion-based. How to change it?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question, closed-questions

I asked the following question a couple of days ago:

[Difference in material covered between Zwiebach or Adams quant mech I on mit ocw?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/536209/)

The original question was deemed opinion-based (which I in hind sight can agree with), so I edited the question. I instead asked if anyone who had experience with both could tell me whether there was a difference in what material was covered between the two courses. That formulation (i.e. the current one) was still deemed opinion-based. What is required in terms of reformulation the question in order for it to be reopened?

Comment: Since it was closed for being opinion based, I think the first thing you should do is make it not opinion based. To be honest I'm not sure how you could do that for this question though.

Comment: @AaronStevens The thing is that I don't see how it is opinion-based now. I'm not asking whether one is better or what someone prefers. It is just a question of how they differ in the materials, whether one is more advanced than the other, whether one is covering more material or is more concentrated etc. Like I wrote in a comment to the question, the fact that both still exist on mit's official account suggest that there is some difference between them, not necessarily in terms of quality of teaching, but in what is covered by the two professors, hence something objective and not opinion-based

Comment: "more advanced" and "more concentrated" are subjective ideas. Even "how they differ" is subjective. You are asking a more open-ended question, which is not on topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone have experience from both of these that can tell me how they differ in the material covered (or if there even is any difference)?

Users would most likely not agree on how similar/different the courses are. Therefore, this is still a subjective question, so it should still be closed as "opinion-based".

This site is not for discussing the differences between certain courses and their material, so I don't really see how you could make this question on topic and reopened.

Comment: Alright, fair enough. I'll accept that it is considered opinion-based then

Comment: I see a difference between "how similar are these courses?" and "how are these courses different, if they are?"  though.  I could see a case for comparing courses being off topic, but is that really shown anywhere?

Comment: @JMac I just don't think there is a definitive answer. People can agree or disagree on how "different" certain courses are.

Comment: @AaronStevens But can they disagree on "do they differ in the material covered"?

Comment: @JMac Maybe not in general topics, but there can be disagreement on how much/well it is actually covered.